# Проверить на наличие атрибута у объектов queryset Django

Tags: python, django

В админке Django мне нужны лишь определенные объекты модели. Для этого я получаю кастомный queryset:

```py
...
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).filter(type__sys_name = 'staff')
```

Однако, атрибут `type` модели необязательный, у некоторых объектов он незаполнен, и я получаю ошибку `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sys_name'`. Как мне проверить на наличие этого атрибута, и получить нужную выборку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно отфильтровать те объекты, у которых нет `type`:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    return super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).filter(
        type__isnull=False, type__sys_name = 'staff')
```